# how to find comma or other symbols in a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's assume I have an string... I want to convert them to numbers.. and It will only work for alphabets...

if my string contains comma or dot... I would like to avoid it...
I'm working with words by word. so if the string is--

```
"Hi, let's play!"
```

it should be converted to--

```
 "4510, 584578'52 69775246!"
```

how can I do it?

```
 function hasNumber(gottenWord) {
        return (/\d/.test(gottenWord));
    }
    const numberTrue =  hasNumber(gottenWord);
```

I was able to search for numbers but not sure how to search for symbols.. and I even have some custom symbols to search.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to avoid anything that's not in `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` then the easiest way is to change `\d` to `[^a-zA-Z]`. `[]` indicates a character set, and starting a set with `^` means "not these".